# How to handle Long texts in <Text> in react native

Tags: text, react-native

I have a long text which I have to put in `<Text>` tag, I have used `numberOfLines={5}`, still it is getting truncated.

Which property should I use ?

Comment: what are you trying to "handle"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need property,

just put text in a tag view and text will adapt to property of View.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
<Text>Ad sint scripta theophrastus sed. Vide mandamus ut nec, et mea vide magna nostro. Ea laboramus scriptorem duo, nonumy sanctus legimus no vim, sea ex quidam vivendo. Et ferri consulatu eam, docendi corpora intellegam no vim, ubique perpetua est in.

An vix denique omittam consequat. Cu erat dictas aperiri vis. Cum esse consetetur te, mei ad illum inani delicata, sea et sumo fabellas. Utamur ponderum est te. His vocent admodum ut, quo habeo dicat ex. Ius id dolorum contentiones, nullam ceteros philosophia nam id.

Erant nonumy eruditi id pro, te sea tollit invidunt patrioque. Ne qui probo consul incorrupte, dico habemus scribentur ne sea, cetero utamur vituperata duo no. Vide solet tritani ut duo. Sit ea option oblique. Idque tantas laoreet ea vel, eu est vocent tritani. Falli verear adolescens usu no, in homero liberavisse cum, dolorem voluptua mel ad.

Mei natum timeam verterem ne, elitr euismod quaerendum vix ea. Ei cum quod sanctus torquatos, ea accusamus gloriatur mei. Sit ea vidit nonumes dissentiet, in pro summo cetero audiam. Vim et zril menandri legendos, ut simul nominavi eligendi vel. Sed at cibo mutat aperiam, id velit audiam assueverit sea, eligendi similique forensibus est ad. Elitr legere philosophia ne eos.
</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Not really, if you put a text of 22100 chars the whole component goes blank. My terms and conditions agreement is about 25k characters, so the whole thing doesn't work.

Comment: i use webView that reference an HTML webpage.

Comment: your solution is not working, i have a very long text but it <Text> do not show full text it show only half of it

Comment: I believe you have a length limit about Text, I don't know how things evolved so far didn't work on RN since a year from now, but anyway setting up a text with 20K+ characters is not something great in term of UX, I mean your user will never read this, and even if you make a kindle like app you can still setup a page system to make it more fluid. So basically I'd recommend to either split your text into many ones or just create an HTML page like the solution below if your text is about conditions agreement.

Answer (score 0):

use webView:

Just include all your text in a webpage and use webview to display it in the app.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://YOURWEBSITE.COM/PRIVACY.HTML'}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```